# How to parse xml link tag href attribute using c#

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, rss

**This is the sample xml of a feed item**

```
 <item>
   <pubDate>2013-12-11 10:28:55</pubDate>
   <title>
     SAG Awards Nominations: 12 Years a Slave, Breaking Bad lead the race
   </title>
   <link>
     http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1929182/news/1929182/
   </link>
   <description>
   <![CDATA[ ]]>
   </description>
   <atom:link rel="thumbnail" type="image/*"  href="http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/36/11173600_tmb.jpg"/>
  </item>
```

**c# code for parsing xml elements**

```
 List<XElement> elementsList = xmlItems.Descendants("item").ToList();
 foreach (XElement rssItem in elementsList)
 {
    RSSItem rss = new RSSItem();
    rss.Description1 = rssItem.Element("description").Value;
    rss.Link1 = rssItem.Element("link").Value;
    rss.Title1 = rssItem.Element("title").Value;
    rss.ImageUrl= ;
 }
```

I successfully parsed the xml elements except the  `atom:link` tag url.
How we can parse the href property from the  `atom:link` tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link has a namespace, you need to indicate it when parsing the XML. I don't remember exactly what namespace `atom` is, but it should be indicated somewhere in the XML file (usually on the root node). For instance, if it is:

```
<feed xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

Then you need to parse it like this:

```
rss.Link1 = (string)rssItem.Element(XName.Get("link", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")).Attribute("href");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can we handle null reference there?

Comment: Personally I far prefer to construct `XName`s using `XName +(XNamespace, string)` - I find it much easier to read than calling `XName.Get`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, to be perfectly honest I didn't even know you could concatenate a XNamespace and a XName until I read your answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the namespace when you look for the element:

```
XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
...
rss.Link1 = rssItem.Element(atom + "link").Attribute("href").Value;
```

LINQ to XML makes namespace handling *much* simpler than any other XML API I've seen, but you still need to be aware of it. (I'm surprised the other elements aren't in a namespace, to be honest.)

I'd also transform your `foreach` loop into a LINQ query:

```
var items = xmlItems.Descendants("item")
                    .Select(x => new RSSItem {
                         Description1 = x.Element("description").Value,
                         Link1 = x.Element(atom + "link").Attribute("href").Value,
                         Title1 = x.Element("title").Value,
                         ...
                     })
                    .ToList();
```

Also consider using a cast to `string` instead of the `Value` property, if some of the elements may be missing - that will set the relevant property to null, instead of throwing a `NullReferenceException`.

EDIT: If the `link` element is missing, you can fix that with:

```
Link1 = (string) x.Elements(atom + "link").Attributes("href").FirstOrDefault()
```

That will find the first `href` attribute within an atom `link` element, or use null - and then the cast to `string` will just return `null` if there's no attribute. (That's part of the user-defined conversion from `XAttribute` to `string`.)

Comment: How can we handle null reference since atom tag is not present for some items?